# Qt: QCheckBox displays text but doesn't render checkbox

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm trying to display a series of `QCheckBox`es in my Qt application. The text displays properly, but the checkbox itself does not display at all. When clicked, the checkbox does report the "checked" state (verified through a connect), but does not show any visual change.

Here's what a `QCheckBox` looks like when rendered:

[image]

FWIW, here are my system details:

```
OS: Artix Linux x86_64 
Host: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X512DA_X512DA 1.0 
Kernel: 6.2.13-artix1-1 
Uptime: 5 hours, 16 mins 
Packages: 1673 (pacman) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
WM: sway 
Theme: Artix-dark [GTK3] 
Icons: breeze-dark [GTK3] 
Terminal: kitty 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.300GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series 
Memory: 5059MiB / 9894MiB
```

Here is the example used in the picture:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCheckBox>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;

    QCheckBox *box = new QCheckBox("checkb ox :)");
    box->setCheckable(true);

    window->setCentralWidget(box);
    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I expected it to look like this (taken from qt6ct):

[image]

Comment: This is now occuring in other Qt applications such as Qt6ct... when I refresh the Qt6ct page, I get the exact same behavior.

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene same thing happens without a `QMainWindow` and also on a `QRadioButton`. As I outlined in my last comment, other Qt Applications actually seem to have this problem now, so I suspect it's something with theming?

Comment: most likely yes, could you try changing your system theme and icons?

Comment: I'm just now reading about `Qt6ct`, is it possible that debugging could reveal something? try enabling it and see if something related is emitted, see [this](https://github.com/trialuser02/qt6ct) _Debug messages_

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene Tried:
- dark & light
- Windows, Fusion, and kvantum styles
- Breeze Dark, GNOME, MATE Faenza themes
All have the same issue. For kicks and giggles, I ran qt5ct and it does NOT have this issue under any settings.

Comment: interesting! what about enabling debugging? I would also mess around the config files, you could find their locations in that link under _Files and Directories:_

Comment: Debugging didn't reveal anything; I will try messing around with configs and seeing what happens.

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene screwed around with the config and nothing helps. I'm probably gonna ask on the Qt forums because this is not a programming issue at this point.

Comment: I'll provide that info on the Qt forum, but fwiw I'm on Sway (wayland), and I'm not using CMake, I'm using this with a library that requires Gradle. Everything else works, and I don't think it's just what I'm programming since it appears to be a systemwide issue

Comment: Wayland? Maybe you forgot to deploy qt wayland plugins?

Comment: Nope, it has the Wayland platform option. Both Wayland and xcb return no errors.